# JIRA Startup Failed ("The following plugins are required by JIRA, but have not been started")

Tags: linux, jira, jira-plugin

I am faced with the following error when launching Jira.
How would you recommend to address this issue?

```
You cannot access JIRA at present. Look at the table below to identify the reasons

Description

The following plugins are required by JIRA, but have not been started:

Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Project Config Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.jira-project-config-plugin)
Atlassian OAuth Admin Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.admin)
Embedded Gadgets Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.embedded)
Gadget Dashboard Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.dashboard)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Look And Feel Logo Upload Plugin com.atlassian.jira.lookandfeel)
Atlassian REST - Module Types (com.atlassian.plugins.rest.atlassian-rest-module)
Gadget Spec Publisher Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.publisher)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - REST Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.rest)
Atlassian OAuth Service Provider Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider)
Atlassian OAuth Consumer Plugin (com.atlassian.oauth.consumer)
Opensocial Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.opensocial)
Gadget Directory Plugin (com.atlassian.gadgets.directory)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - SAL Plugin (com.atlassian.sal.jira)
Atlassian JIRA - Plugins - Gadgets Plugin (com.atlassian.jira.gadgets)
```

Comment: How did you try to start Jira?

Comment: sh start-jira.sh   localhost:8080

Comment: I agree with Kuf, can you accept an answer or comment to say nothing worked? it helps people directed her by google

Answer (score 8):

[This thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/25928/how-to-resolve-the-plugins-failed-to-load-error) lists various possible causes:

- [bug JRA-22633](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-22633) is about increasing the timeout at the beginning of the session
- potential Java version issue:  "I just had this same issue and found that apparently JIRA doesn't work properly on Java 1.7. If you downgrade to 1.6 everything runs smoothly."
- check if the anti-virus isn't the cause (see [this thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/39168/jira-startup-failed-you-cannot-access-jira-at-present-look-at-the-table-below-to-identify-the-reasons) for illustration)
- some plugin could be disabled: see "[JIRA does not Start Due to Disabled Bundled Plugin](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/JIRA+does+not+Start+Due+to+Disabled+Bundled+Plugin)"
- make sure there is no Jira locking issue (see "[JIRA is Locked](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/JIRA+is+Locked)")

Comment: Nice summary of possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue today, where in the end JIRA would be locked after a restart. This was caused because the plugin **com.atlassian.jira.ext.rpc** was disabled. This, however, did not happen because it couldn't load properly due a timeout issue. It happened, I think, because upgrading the add-ons took longer than expected so JIRA disabled the plugin on purpose. I could have enabled it manually, but failed to notice it and restarted JIRA right away. Now the plugin was still disabled and I had no chance of changing it, since JIRA didn't start.

I fixed this manually, by connecting to the database and running the following:
**update pluginstate set pluginenabled='true' where pluginkey='com.atlassian.jira.ext.rpc';**
This was set to **false** before. I then started JIRA again and it worked.